# Signing a commit reversion on GitHub

Tags: github

My GitHub repository requires all commits to be signed before they can be merged. However, when I revert a commit through the web interface, the created commit is not signed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How are you performing the revert?  Through the web interface, or the command line?

Comment: Through the web interface. Post updated, thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for that @sigma1510 ?